# Ubuntu 16.04 can't find bluetooth devices

Tags: bluetooth, headset, blueman

Recently got a new laptop and successfully installed Ubuntu on it.
However, unlike my other debian laptops, this one seems unable to discover my bluetooth headset.

I tried using `bluetoothctl`:

```
power on
agent on
default-agent
scan on
```

no error messages, but no results came out.

Then I tried `hcitool`:

> hcitool scan

but still came blank.

Blueman also wasn't of much help.
The bluetooth interfaces weren't blocked either, according to `rfkill`

I noticed that this appeared in my dmesg:

> bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2

Finally, the output of `sudo service bluetooth status` is

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-01-07 15:57:22 GMT; 41min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 1015 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─1015 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jan 07 16:23:33 towc bluetoothd[1015]: Current Time Service could not be registered
Jan 07 16:23:33 towc bluetoothd[1015]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error (5)
Jan 07 16:23:33 towc bluetoothd[1015]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jan 07 16:23:33 towc bluetoothd[1015]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jan 07 16:23:33 towc bluetoothd[1015]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Jan 07 16:23:33 towc bluetoothd[1015]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Jan 07 16:23:33 towc bluetoothd[1015]: Failed to get connections: Not Powered (0x0f)
Jan 07 16:23:33 towc bluetoothd[1015]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.61 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jan 07 16:23:33 towc bluetoothd[1015]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.61 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jan 07 16:23:33 towc bluetoothd[1015]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
```

Output of lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0930:0225 Toshiba Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b446 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Any suggestions on what to try now?

Comment: Your BT device is `0930:0225`. I added support of this device to the kernel. http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-xenial.git/commit/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c?id=36877fcdcb200d3163b11f82d594bd7dfec5ec36

Comment: @Pilot6 so what do I do? Still looking through that answer

Comment: Use that answer to get `BCM.hcd` file.

Comment: @Pilot6 turning off and on again, I'll let you know

Comment: @Pilot6 I don't seem to be having any dmesg errors or anything now, but when I try putting the power on via bluetoothctl, it says `No default controller available` -_-

Comment: @Pilot6 blueman says it can't find adaptors

Comment: Are you sure you converted the correct file? Not the one that is in the other answer?

Comment: @Pilot6 for me that would be `BCM43142A0_001.001.011.0197.0217.hex`, right? I then turned it into `BCM43142A0-0930-0225.hcd` using `hex2hcd`, and when I noticed that the output of `cat /proc/version` was `Linux version 4.4.0-57-generic (buildd@lgw01-54) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ) #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 9 23:50:32 UTC 2016` I renamed it to `BCM.hcd`, and finally copied that into `/lib/firmware/brcm`

Comment: It looks correct. The BT should work. What about `rfkill list`?

Comment: @Pilot6 nothing blocked:

`0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no`

Comment: @Pilot6 just re-powered off and on again. Controller issue is fixed for some reason. Thanks. Should I delete the question?

Comment: Keep the question. It will point other people the right direction.